# How to print an array within an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

So, i have a class named Hospital and a method called InsertFolders inside the Hospital class.
Inside the method the user must fill an array(max 5) of examinations (I made a class called Folders where i have the set and get methods for the array).
Now i have created another method called print where i want to print this array.
Note that there is an array of objects which contains the Folders.
ListOfFolders[i].getNameOfFolder(this is the field of the folder's name for example).
Is there a way where i can print the array?
For example when i try ListOfFolders[i].getArrayOfExaminations() it doesn't print the expected examinations.

Comment: Create a toString method on the objects you want to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `toString` function like:

```
public class Person{
   private int id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lasrName;
   .
   .

   public Person(){
       this.id = 1;
       this.firstName = "First Name";
       this.lastName = "Last Name";
   }

   public String toString(){
       String str = "";

       str += "Person Info: \n";
       str += "Id : " + id + "\n";
       str += "First Name : " + firstName + "\n";
       str += "Last Name : " + lastName + "\n";
       ....

       return str;
   }   

}
```

If you would share us your code I would have implement it better, but this is the idea.

**Usage:**

```
List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
list.add(new Person());

for (YourClass item : list){
      System.out.println(item);  //here it will automaticly use the overridden toString in your class
}
```

**Output:**

```
Person Info:
Id: 1
First Name
Last Name
```

Comment: When i tried the first example you gave me it stopped printing the address but it did print nothing at all. May i ask fo further explanation because i think that this is the solution but i am missing something. Thank you.

Comment: You need to `Override` the `toString` function like I did in `YourClass` example above, this function needs to return a String as you build it by your request, let's say it return's like that: `return "string from toString function";` Then you will see it while using println function

Comment: I made my example much more simple for you to understand, I hope that it's fine like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just printing an object prints the reference (~address) to it by default. You need to override the toString() method for the object to make it print the proper value.

If this is the default array in Java, you can loop over the objects in the array with the for(item : array) syntax.